# Yii2 UrlManager config

Tags: php, yii2

I have a UrlRoute as below:

```
<?= Url::toRoute(['/site/show-post', 'id' => $model->id, 'type_id' => $model->type_id]) ?>
```

which give the result as
mysitename.com/site/show-post/1405?type_id=1

I want to add the post title to url and I modified the above as

```
<?= Url::toRoute(['/site/show-post', 'id' => $model->id, 'type_id' => $model->type_id,'title'=>$mdoel->title]) ?>
```

which results in:
mysitename.com/site/show-post/1405?type_id=1&title=your+post+title

So it is working fine. but I want to modify it like & it should work getting the same result.
mysitename.com/site/show-post/1405/type_id/1/your+post+title

even here `'id'=>$model->id` is returning as I expect that is `/show-post/1405` but the subsequent parameter is resulting in query-string

I also tried in config.php under - UrlManager like this:

```
'<controller:[A-Za-z-]+>/<id:\d+>/<type_id:\d+>/<title>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```

but it doesn't seems to work.

How I can achieve it like what I mentioned.

Comment: Did you tried to add proper regex for `title` param? For example `<controller:[A-Za-z-]+>/<id:\d+>/<type_id:\d+>/<title:.+>`.

Comment: Hi Rob, I did just similar - `<controller:[A-Za-z-]+>/<id:\d+>/<type_id:\d+>/<title:w+>` but I am getting it like `mysitename.com/site/show-post/1405/your+post+title?type_id=1` and not /type_id/1, any reason why still like this?

Comment: This URL does not match your rule at all, it may be generated by another rule. Also your pattern does not make sense - `w+` literally  means "one or more `w` chars". It will work only if your title contains only `w`.

Comment: So sorry, it is `<title:\w+>`, I missed the slash here, but it is there in the config.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
'<controller:[A-Za-z-]+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<type_id:\d+>/<title>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```

Answer (score -1):

The method you are following is correct and the results you are getting are the expected result. I am not sure what you meant by query language, but what understand is you want the clean urls instead of extra characters being added to your urls. For this you will have to implement pretty urls for yii2.
Here is how you can get pretty urls in yii2, add the following code to your configs:

```
'urlManager' => [
'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
// Disable index.php
'showScriptName' => false,
// Disable r= routes
'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
'rules' => array(
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
),
```

],